# Show hide a div clicking on another div and closing it by click anywhere outside

Tags: jquery, panel, selector

I have this html:

```
<div class="trigger">
    My button
</div>

<div class="panel">
    <span class="close-btn"></span>
        My panel
</div>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
$('.panel').fadeIn("fast");
$(this).toggleClass('isOpen');
});


$(".close-btn").click(function() {
$('.panel').fadeToggle("fast");
$('.trigger').removeClass('isOpen');
});

$('.panel').hover(function() {
mouse_is_inside = true;
}, function() {
mouse_is_inside = false;
});

$("body").mouseup(function() {
if (!mouse_is_inside) $('.panel').fadeOut("fast");
$('.trigger').removeClass('isOpen');
});

if ($(".trigger").hasClass('isOpen')) {
$('.panel').fadeOut("fast");
}​
```

What I want to do is:

1. open the panel and then,
2. close it by clicking anywhere in the page but in the panel itself,
3. on the closing button inside the panel and,
4. on the div that opened it.

but I can't get it to work as when the panel is open the div "trigger" gets confused and keeps opening and closing the panel due to the function that allows me to click anywhere in the page.

Thanks for help

Comment: Try looking at the login (Accedi) button in top right page at http://www.360kayak.org/. Is this the effect you want?

Comment: Yes Alessandro that is what I'd like to do but obviously with a fade and not with a slide effect. :=)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a not beautiful solution:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $('.panel').fadeIn("fast");
});

$(".close-btn, .panel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.panel').fadeOut("fast");
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!(e.target.className == 'trigger' || e.target.className == 'panel' || e.target.className == 'close-btn')) {
        $('.panel').fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kavh4/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've implemented this in http://www.360kayak.org : http://pastebin.com/UVvELYES

I hope it can be a inspiration.

The solution is `event.stopPropagation();` and calling `stop()` before `animate()`
My animation is a slideUp/slideDown, not a fade, but it should work even with fade.

This part manages the "click outside to close".

```
$('html').click( function(event) {
        var formWrapper = $("#block-user-login-form-wrapper");
        if (formWrapper != null && formWrapper.position() != null && formWrapper.position().top == 0) {
          $("#block-user-login-form-wrapper").stop().animate({
            top: "-128px"
          }, null, null, function() {
            $("#signin-button").addClass("enabled");
          });
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
      });
```

And this prevent to slideup the form when you click it

```
  $("#block-user-login-form").click( function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```